# On-the-fly formatting a stream of JSON using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I've a Json string that is not indended, e.g.,:

```json
{"hash":"123","id":456}
```

I want to indent the string and serialize it to a JSON file. Naively, I can indent the string using `Newtonsoft` as follows.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
var formattedJson = JObject.Parse(token.ToString()).ToString();
```

However, since I am using a decent number of large JSON objects, I am mainly interested in solutions that can operate on a stream of data. For performance reasons, I have decided to use `System.Text.Json`, and I am wondering if it comes with any out-of-box functionality for processing data streams.

Before rolling my own solution, I am wondering if there is any approach with mostly out-of-box functionality ideally intercepting a stream of the input while it is written to storage (i.e., on-the-fly conversion). Alternatively, I can process a serialized stream, but that needs to read through the file, make the necessary changes, and write to the output file without requiring to deserialize the entire JSON into memory first. I am mainly interested in the first approach because (a) I would be going through the JSON once, and (b) that does not require storing an intermediate file (stream -> unformatted-JSON -> formatted-JSON).

### Motivation

An upstream service is streaming a large collection of information in JSON format. A downstream service reads through the JSON in a line-by-line fashion and extracts the required fields; presumably motivated by the large size of the JSON files that makes them impractical/infeasible to deserialize in memory. However, there are a few conventions to happen on the streamed JSON to make it compatible with the downstream service. One of the required conventions is indentation and one-key-value-pair-per-line. It seems the upstream service is dropping all the formatting to stream fewer bits, but the downstream relies on the formatting to extract information. Both upstream and downstream services are beyond my control. The goal of the service I'm writing is to sit in the middle and make the necessary conventions (formattings such as indentation is one of them) on the streamed JSON to make it compatible with the downstream service.

As explained above, deserializing the streamed JSON into an object, making the necessary changes, and serializing the updated JSON to disk, seems an obvious solution, however, given the size and the volume of data, this approach is impractical/infeasible for my application.

I can think of a middle layer that processes the streamed JSON on the fly and makes the changes before writing the bits to a persistence media. However, before going that path, I wanted to double-check if there is any out-of-box functionality in `System.Text.Json` to process streams of information.

## Update

The question is largely updated for clarity and emphasis on the main point: is there any out-of-box functionality in `System.Text.Json` for processing stream of JSON?

Comment: What do you mean by "format the string"?

Comment: Indented and removed trailing commas is what I'm mainly looking for.

Comment: If you ask Json.net or System.Text.Json to serialize a string, it will escape those quotes. The saving grace in your Json.net example was that you first parsed the string into an object model, and then you serialized that. You don't need to parse and serialize it twice though, just do `token.ToString()` if by "formatted" you mean one property per line and indented.

Comment: To reformat the json you first have to parse it.

Comment: How about `JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json), new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true })` ?

Comment: Serializing a deserialized string is a good suggestion, thank you. However, since this piece of code will run for a decent number of times on large JSON objects (retried via REST API), I was wondering if there is any more efficient alternative.

Comment: You can write your own json prettyprinter implementation, that just reads through the json sequentially and reformats it as it goes along. This will be much much more efficient both in terms of time spent and memory used. Likely I would start by checking nuget packages for someone having done that, or perhaps even json.net has this built in.

Comment: May I ask *why* you need to do this? If you have JSON content large enough that deserializing and serializing it will create a noticeable performance impact, I would gather that the JSON content is not really for human reading anyway. May I ask what kind of problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That is a valid concern; I added the motivation to the question, hopefully, that clarifies a bit.

Comment: If you just restrict yourself to .NET built-in solutions I believe you can do this with `JsonReaderWriterFactory`; would that answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there's no easy way to do it with `System.Text.Json` because you cannot use a `Stream` object with the `System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader` directly. To bypass this limitation, you need to put the file content into memory with the `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument` object so obviously, it will take up a lot of memory.

For now, with what a read on the web, the only solution to be **memory efficient** is to use **Newtonsoft.Json** library.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(sourceFilePath))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
using (var streamWriter = File.CreateText(destinationFilePath))
using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
{
    jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
    {
        jsonTextWriter.WriteToken(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

Much faster with 1MB buffer instead of the default 4kB.
Indented a 6.33 GB file in 5m05s to 13.7 GB, a total of around 200.000.000 lines. It was reading and writing on a HDD, running in Visual Studio (Debug release) and only uses 17MB RAM. Couldn't test on SSD because of space limitation.

```cs
string filename = @"VeryBig.json";
using FileStream inputFileStream = new(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1 * 1024 * 1024);
using StreamReader streamReader = new(inputFileStream);
using JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new(streamReader);

string filenameOutput = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, ".indented.json");
using FileStream outputFileStream = new(filenameOutput, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 1 * 1024 * 1024);
using StreamWriter streamWriter = new(outputFileStream);
using JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new(streamWriter);

jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

while (jsonTextReader.Read())
{
    jsonTextWriter.WriteToken(jsonTextReader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested and didn' t find any problem

```
var json="{\"hash\":\"123\",\"id\":456}";

var jsonObject=JsonDocument.Parse(json);

json =  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonObject, 
new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
```

test result

```
{
  "hash": "123",
  "id": 456
}
```

Comment: Youre using `JsonDocument.Parse` which create another object and also parses the whole json a second time.

Comment: @Charles you can serialize as many times as you like ,  but you can't not parse twice, it will cause an exception. When you parse using System.Text.Json  it creates a JsonDocument, and you can not parce  again.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to avoid parsing it to an object, mainly because I am using large JSON strings that take a good amount of CPU time and memory space to be parsed. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Hamed Just because of curiousity. Why do you need to make the extra intends on gigabytes of json. It is thousands and thousands pages that nobody will be able to see. On the contrary it  should be ziped , to save some space.

Comment: @Serge I was curious about it as well, and it was explained to me that the JSON files are processed downstream by a service that reads through it line-by-line and uses indentation to infer the nesting level (seemingly that was the easiest approach to extra info from large JSON without having to read it to memory).

Comment: @Hamed the should be formatted immediately at API level. I don't understand why it should be converted to  unformatted json and after this parsed and converted again. It is radiculous.

Comment: You're correct; though unfortunately, both upstream and downstream services are beyond my touch.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way using `System.Text.Json` and friends:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{

  const string template = @"
Original:
---------
{0}
---------

Pretty:
---------
{1}
---------
";

  public static void Main()
  {
    var src  = "{\"hash\":\"123\",\"id\":456}";
    
    using ( var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(src, new JsonDocumentOptions{ AllowTrailingCommas = true }) )
    using ( var ms  = new MemoryStream() )
    using ( var jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter( ms, new JsonWriterOptions{ Indented = true } ) )
    {
      
      doc.RootElement.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
      
      jsonWriter.Flush();
      ms.Flush();
      
      string pretty = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
      
      Console.WriteLine( template , src, pretty );
      
    }
        
  }
}
```

Which produces the expected

```
Original:
---------
{"hash":"123","id":456}
---------
Pretty:
---------
{
  "hash": "123",
  "id": 456
}
---------
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I am afraid parsing JSON string to an object then serializing it back is not ideal for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any out-of-box functionality in System.Text.Json for processing stream of JSON?

Yes... sort of.

You can [use Utf8JsonReader to read from a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#read-from-a-stream-using-utf8jsonreader). But it doesn't support streams natively: it relies on `ReadOnlySequence<>`s. So the code for streaming with it is pretty gnarly, and involves creating your own buffers and reading from the stream yourself.